# Check if an XML node exists, using Tinyxml 

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I am using tinyXml for parsing an XML file in C++. Could anyone please tell me how do I check to see if a node (parent/child/next sibling) exists or not. Below are the only nodes present in the xml file I'm working on.

```
TiXmlElement* Instrmt = TrdCaptRpt->FirstChildElement();
TiXmlElement* Undly = Instrmt->NextSiblingElement();
TiXmlElement* Amt = Undly->NextSiblingElement();
TiXmlElement* RptSide = Amt->NextSiblingElement();
TiXmlElement* Pty = RptSide->FirstChildElement();
```

if any of the nodes above is missing in the sequence then the program aborts with a segmentation fault.

Could anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: For each pointer, always check if it is NULL before using it. It will solve your crash issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `const TiXmlNode* TiXmlNode::FirstChild (   const char *    value    )   const` function of the `TiXmlNode` class and check if the resulting `TiXmlNode*` is `NULL` or not.

```
TiXmlNode* child = mynode->FirstChild();

if (child != NULL)
{
  //A child exists....
}
```

For Parent you have a similar function.  You can find the documentation [here](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#1f05828d023150706eeb16d6fb3f6355).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

TiXml provides the [TiXMlHandle](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlHandle.html#_details) class to take care of checking for NULL, so it should sort out the segmentaiton faults. You still need to check the existence of the node at the end of the chain.